# Razer SDK C++ Create Effect

Tags: c++

So I've recently downloaded the razer api or (Razer SDK) to being able to fully unlock the lightning selection for my keyboard, mouse and such. The only issue I'm having with creating stuff is that there isn't a whole lot of tutorials and guides etc etc on the internet. I want to being able to set a color on my Razer Firefly via their Sample application that you get with their SDK package.

I've found where to write the code but I haven't found how to write it with clear examples.

This is what it should look like (in my mind):

```
void CAlertDlg::OnBnClickedButtonPositiveAlert()
{
   RZRESULT CreateEffect(RZDEVICEID FIREFLY_CHROMA, 
   ChromaSDK::STATIC_EFFECT_TYPE, RZEFFECTID CHROMA_STATIC, RZCOLOR RED);
}
```

But when I click the button that is supposed to load the effect, nothing happens. This is what it says on Razer's SDK website:

```
RZRESULT CreateMousepadEffect    (  ChromaSDK::Mousepad::EFFECT_TYPE    
                                    Effect,
                                    PRZPARAM    pParam,
                                    RZEFFECTID *    pEffectId 
                                 )
```

The effect I'm trying to set on the Razer Firefly Chroma is a normal Static Red.

Thank you in advance for any tips / help.

Comment: This is simply a basic syntax problem. You're not calling the function, you're *declaring* it. Calling it would be e.g. `RZRESULT some_variable = CreateEffect(FIREFLY_CHROMA, ChromaSDK::STATIC_EFFECT_TYPE, CHROMA_STATIC, RED)`.

Comment: So, basically there isn't a premade function for setting the effects, I simply has to make them myself? If I understand your comment correctly.

Comment: I did find another file for their "tester" software, and there it was a set of code that seems to be working, so now if I'm correct I have created an effect, I'm just not able to apply it, which is a huge problem, might be easy to solve though, I have done programming in c++ before, though I'm not so very good at it so alot of this stuff is not as clear to me as it might be to others sadly.

Comment: I did figure it out, it works now. Thank you for the help :)